# Como adicionar itens à uma lista de produtos vindo de uma api com React

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Tenho um sistema que preciso pesquisar por um produto em uma api pelo nome, cada vez que clicar em adicionar preciso pegar o retorno da api  e incluir esse produto uma lista calculando o valor total e quantidade.

Conforme descrito abaixo, iniciei o useState com as propriedades do objeto vazia, preciso alterar a quantidade e o total a cada vez que o usuário adicionar uma nova unidade, a api me retorna o nome e o preço unitário, a quantidade de produtos é inserida antes de adicionar na lista.

```
export default function ProductList(){
    const [product, setProduct] = useState('');

    const [item, setItemList] = 
    useState([
       {
         'produto': '',
         'preco': '',
         'quantidade': 0,
         'total': 0
       }

    ]);


function handleAddProduct(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    async function getProducts() {
        let response = await api.get(`product/${product}`);
        let { produto, preco } = response.data[0];
        var qte = 1;

        setItemList([{
                'produto': produto,
                'preco': preco,
                'quantidade': qte++,
                'total':  preco * qtde     
        }])
    }

    getProducts(); 
}


return (
     <div className={style.contentLeft}>
             <form action="" onSubmit='' method="get">
              <h2>Produtos</h2> 
                <div className={style.formGroup}>
                    <label htmlFor="">Buscar nome do produto </label>
                    <input type="text" name="product"  onChange={e => setProduct(e.target.value)}  style={{ width: '400px'}} placeholder="Digite aqui o que procura"/>
                </div>

                <div className={style.formGroup}>
                  <label htmlFor="">Quantidade de itens</label>
                  <input type="number" name="itens" min="1" onChange={e => setProductQuantity(e.target.value)}  placeholder="Quantidade de itens"  />
                </div>

                <div className={style.formGroup}>
                   <button type="submit" name="adicionar" onClick={handleAddProduct}>Adicionar</button>
                </div>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Produto/Serviço</th>
                            <th>Quantidade</th>
                            <th>Preço unitário</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         {item.map(itemName => {
                            return (
                             <>
                                <td> Livro </td>
                                <td> 2 </td>
                                <td>R$ 29,90</td>
                                <td>R$ 59,80</td>
                                <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
                             </>
                                     
                             )
                         })}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
             </form>
         </div> )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `setItemList([ ...item, { /* novo item */ ])`, é isso?

Comment: Seria isso, mas quando adicionar o mesmo item preciso somente alterar a quantidade e o total, fiz assim só que cada vez que adiciono na lista ele gera um novo valor para o mesmo item.

Comment: Mas cada produto tem o total e quantidade ? Como é que está a utilizar isso em cada produto ?

Comment: A api só me devolve o nome do produto e preço, a partir daí eu defino quantos unidades quero adicionar na lista, atualizando a quantidade e o subtotal se já existir o produto na lista.